# Invoking JAX-WS web services from remote machine using JQuery and AJAX

Tags: ajax, web-services, jax-ws

I am new to Java SOAP web services. Recently I have created a web service using the JAX-WS specification. This is deployed in the WebLogic server I am using in my machine. Now when I want to invoke the web service from the web application written in JavaScript remote machine on another server, it giving me the following error.

I have also browsed for some other similar kind of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214611/how-to-call-java-web-service-jax-ws-from-ajax)
[image: cross-domain invocation denied]

I am sending the request using JavaScript and SoapClient.js Library.

My invocation code is:

```
SOAPClient.invoke("http://inhydkvaranasi1:7001/TodoWS/TodoListService",
            "getTodos", p1, true, function(data) {
                $("#todolist").html('');
                if (Object.keys(data).length < 1) {
                    $("#todolist").html(
                            "<h4>No Todos Available right now!</h4>");
                } else {
                    Object.keys(data).forEach(
                            function(key) {
                                $("#todolist").append(
                                        "<li>" + data[key]["task1"]
                                                + "(Priority "
                                                + data[key]["id0"]
                                                + ") </p>");
                            });
                }
            });
```

The request sent by the `XMLHttpRequest()` object did not get a response header as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the XML response.

How could I solve this problem? So that my web service can be used publicly by any user from different domain on different server.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [**CORS HTTP headers**](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (from [codingpedia.org](http://www.codingpedia.org)):

**Client side HTTP request headers**. These are headers that clients may use when issuing HTTP requests in order to make use of the cross-sharing feature:

> - [Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#origin-request-header): *URI indicating the server from which the request initiated.  It does not include any path information, but only the
>     server name*
> - [Access-Control-Request-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-request-headers-request-header):  *used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know what HTTP headers will be used when the
>     actual request is made*
> - [Access-Control-Request-Method](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-request-method-request-header): *used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know what HTTP method will be used when the
>     actual request is made*

**Server side HTTP response headers**. These are the HTTP headers that the server sends back for access control requests:

> - [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header): *specifies the authorized domains to make* *cross-domain request (you should include the domains of your*
>     *clients or* “*” *if you want the resource public and available to*
>     *everyone – the latter is not an option if credentials are allowed*
>     *during CORS requests)*
> - [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header): *lets a server white list headers that browsers are allowed to access*
> - [Access-Control-Max-Age](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-max-age-response-header):  *indicates how long the results of a preflight request can be cached*.
> - [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-credentials-response-header): *indicates if the server allows credentials during CORS requests*
> - [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header):
>     *indicates the methods allowed when accessing the resource*
> - [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-headers-response-header):  *used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the
>     actual request*